# How to calculate the tangent line of $\ln(x)$ through $(2,6)$ by hand?

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, tangent-line

I came up with my own question for a tutor student, but now I am stuck myself.

The exercise was to calculate the equation of a tangent-line of $f(x) = \ln(x)$, which goes through the point $(2,6)$.
I'm trying to solve the problem by hand, but the equations I get to solve the problem aren't solveable with the lineair algebra I'm aware of. Is this right, or am I missing something?

Representation of the problem, where the green line represents $\ln(x), A = (2,6)$ and the black line is the unknown which should be calculated:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5ZEt.png]

Comment: What do you mean by solving the problem “by hand?”

Comment: Without using a calculator/algebraically :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that the inclination of the line is equal to the derivative of the function on the point in witch they intersect. Then

$ \cfrac{6-\ln x}{2-x}=\cfrac{1}{x}$ 
which implies

$x(7-\ln(x))- 2 = 0$.

Can you solve from here?

Comment: Ah, of course, thanks Ricardo! I was using the same equation, but for the 'touching point' I used new variables, which made the problem way harder than it actually was.

Comment: The resulting transcendental equation probably do not have elementary solution. But with help of [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Solving_equations), it can be expressed as $x = e^{7+W_k (-2e^{-7})},\ k=0,1$

Answer (score 2):

Derivative of $ \log x$ is $\dfrac{1}{x}$.

Point/slope form of a straight line:

$$ \dfrac{log\, x -6}{x-2}= \frac{1}{x}$$

Simplify

$$ x \,log\, x -7x +2 =0 $$

Only numerical solution possible to find tangent point from this transcendental equation. Has two solutions with approx. values:

$$x=(0.23697, 1094.6 ) $$

Take logs of above to find $y$ values for the two $x$ values.

$$y= (-1.43981, 6.99817).$$

EDIT1:

In your sketch only the first root appears correctly. In order that the second root be also seen, a *separate graph* has to be made with a larger domain upto say $x=1100$ and aspect ratio say $\dfrac12.$

Answer (score 1):

The equation
$$x \log( x) -7x +2 =0$$ has two solutions in terms of Lambert function. They are
$$x_1=-\frac{2}{W_{-1}\left(-\frac{2}{e^7}\right)}\approx0.236972 \qquad \text{and} \qquad x_2=-\frac{2}{W\left(-\frac{2}{e^7}\right)}\approx1094.63$$

The bounds for the smallest root can be estimated using
$$-1-\sqrt{2u}-u < W_{-1}(-e^{-u-1}) < -1-\sqrt{2u}-\frac{2}{3}u$$ Using $u=6-\log(2)$, this gives
$$-7+\log (2)-\sqrt{2 (6-\log (2))}<W_{-1}\left(-\frac{2}{e^7}\right)<-5+\frac{2 \log (2)}{3}-\sqrt{2 (6-\log (2))}$$ that is to say
$$0.209102 < x_1 <0.256549$$ Starting at $x_0=\frac e{10}$ (this is close to the midpoint), the first  iterate of Newton method will be
$$x_1=\frac{20-e}{10 (5+\log (10))}\approx 0.236652$$

Comment: [GKZ] p. 17: the dual curve has the parametrization $p = p(t), q = q (t),$ where $p(t)x +q (t) y+ 1 = 0$
is the affine equation of the tangent line to $X$ at $(x(t), y(t))$. Using this on the parametrization of the graph of $y=\ln{x}$ 

$$(x,y)=(t,\ln{t})\to (p,q)=(\frac{-y'}{x'y-xy'},\frac{x'}{x'y-xy'})=(\frac{-\frac{1}{t}}{\ln{t}-1},\frac{1}{\ln{t}-1})$$

$$2p+6q-1=0$$

$\frac{-2}{t}+6-\ln{t}+1=0$ or $-2+7t-t\ln{t}=0$ as you show we get $t_1\approx 0.236972,t_2\approx 1094.63$, and then the tangents are $\frac{\frac{-1}{t_i}}{\ln{t_i}-1} x+\frac1{\ln{t_i}-1} y-1=0$